# Recognizing Excel Date formatted column in .csv file as a Date for time series conversion

Tags: r, csv, time-series, xts

I have downloaded the DJI historical data from Yahoo as a csv for further analysis in R. Out of curiosity `getSymbols("^DJI")` didn't seem to work, but I digress.

The point is that I don't know how to turn this `csv` file into a time series format.

Here is the output and problem so far:

```
> DJI = read.csv("^DJI.csv")
> head(DJI)
       Date    Open    High     Low   Close Adj.Close   Volume
1 1/29/1985 1277.72 1295.49 1266.89 1292.62   1292.62 13560000
2 1/30/1985 1297.37 1305.10 1278.93 1287.88   1287.88 16820000
3 1/31/1985 1283.24 1293.40 1272.64 1286.77   1286.77 14070000
4  2/1/1985 1276.94 1286.11 1269.77 1277.72   1277.72 10980000
5  2/4/1985 1272.08 1294.94 1268.99 1290.08   1290.08 11630000
6  2/5/1985 1294.06 1301.13 1278.60 1285.23   1285.23 13800000
> chartSeries(DJI)
Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object
```

So the `{quantmod}` function `chartSerie` is requesting an `.xts` file, but the `Date` column in `DJI` is not immediately recognized as such:

```
> DJI = as.Date(DJI$Date)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

---

EDIT after the answer below:

```
> head(DJI)
              Open    High     Low   Close Adj.Close   Volume
1985-01-29 1277.72 1295.49 1266.89 1292.62   1292.62 13560000
1985-01-30 1297.37 1305.10 1278.93 1287.88   1287.88 16820000
1985-01-31 1283.24 1293.40 1272.64 1286.77   1286.77 14070000
1985-02-01 1276.94 1286.11 1269.77 1277.72   1277.72 10980000
1985-02-04 1272.08 1294.94 1268.99 1290.08   1290.08 11630000
1985-02-05 1294.06 1301.13 1278.60 1285.23   1285.23 13800000
> is.ts(DJI)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Try `DJI$Date <- as.Date(DJI$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you. How do you turn the csv file into an xts file after the step you indicated?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer - needed a bit more space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the dates you need a `format` statement...

```
DJI$Date <- as.Date(DJI$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

`quantmod` needs dates in `xts` objects to be row names rather than a separate column.  You should therefore also do

```
rownames(DJI) <- DJI$Date
DJI$Date <- NULL #to remove the column

chartSeries(DJI)
```

Comment: Even though I can now generate `chartSeries`, please notice the edit to the OP, showing that the final dataset is still not a time series. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `DJI <- as.xts(DJI)`

Comment: Or `as.ts(DJI)` - depending on what sort of time series you need.

Comment: Thank you. It's funny that if I run `is.ts(DJI)` after `DJI <- as.xts(DJI)`, I get `FALSE`. Isn't an `xts` file a `ts`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought!  I think `quantmod` manages to coerce them to the appropriate type, so I'm not sure it matters in this case.